# collection.find not returning any documents to dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pymongo

Having a few issues with returning documents to a dataframe from a MongoDb collection. The code below establishes a connection to mongodb:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
# Connect to the Mongo client. MongoClient is the connection to the MongoDB instance on port 27017 on host hkgdlvasfj001.
client = MongoClient('hkgdlvasfj001', 27017)
# Access the bb i.e. access a collection in PyMongo
#display(client.database_names()) # all the db's in the db i.e. ['admin', 'config', 'gtm', 'local']
# Assign gtm database 
db = client.gtm
```

I can succesfully return a single document from the rfq collection:

```
#display(db.collection_names()) # all collections in the d b i.e ['rfqs', 'trades']                             
# Search for the documents you want
display(db.rfqs.find_one({'Data.State': "Done"}))

Output: 
{'Data': {'Action': 'DealerAcceptOrder',
      'AllQ': '3.09',
      'AutoNegDealerMidValue': '3.09',
      'AutoNegDealerSpread': '0',
      'AutoNegDealerValue': '3.0846',
      'ClearingChannel': '',
      'ClearingCode': 'UNKNOWN',
      'ClearingHouse': 'UNKNOWN',
```

But when I expand the criteria I can't get any documents from my dataframe

```
df = db.rfqs.find({'Data.State' : "Done",'Data.Ticker': "ACGB 3 3/4 04/21/37"})
display(df)
```

Returns `<pymongo.cursor.Cursor at 0x84dc3c8>`

Is there something different I need to do when assigning documents to a datframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your `find()` is returning more than one result. That's why it is a `pymongo.cursor.Cursor` object. To get the object back, try:

```
cursor= db.rfqs.find({'Data.State' : "Done",'Data.Ticker': "ACGB 3 3/4 04/21/37"})
df_list = list() # you can also create an empty dataframe here and concat the df to it later 
for doc in cursor:
    df_list.append(pd.DataFrame(doc))
    print(doc)
```

For more info, read [this](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html).

Comment: ah, ok that expalins it. And the best way to convert my cursor into a pandas datframe?Monary?.to_dict?

Comment: Try `df = pd.Dataframe(doc)` Not sure if you can convert the cursor into a dataframe directly or not. But you can convert the documents inside the cursor to dataframe

Comment: So I have to loop through each doc in the cursor and append to the df?

Comment: @PeterLucas I have updated the answer above. You can try it.

Comment: Nearly there, getting an error AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Dataframe'

Comment: Sorry. A typo here. Should be DataFrame

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170274/discussion-between-peter-lucas-and-r-yan).